# Hide objects in Xcode on 3.5" iOS 6/7 devices

Tags: xcode, ios6, ios7

is it possible, in Xcode 4 or 5, to hide objects on 3.5" iOS 6/7 devices, and show on 4" devices? I'm working on an app and have a full screen on 4", and would like to hide a few objects on 3.5" devices so that it is less cluttered. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also hide objects in your code instead of having two storyboards with all the views duplicated.
For example in your viewDidLoad method do this:

```
if (self.view.frame.size.height < 568) {
    myButton.hidden = YES;
    myTextField.hidden = YES;
    ...
}
```

Or define a macro like this:

```
#define isIPhone5  ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 568)?TRUE:FALSE
```

And use it in all your viewControllers:

```
if (!isIPhone5)
{
    myButton.hidden = YES;
    myTextField.hidden = YES;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several approaches to this problem. You can remove the elements, but you have to then find a way of displaying them on the smaller screen. You can use a scrollview, where the users need to scroll to view the rest of the content. If you go with the former method, you can either remove the elements in code, or if you are using storyboards/nibs, create duplicates for each screen size. Having two storyboards has its advantages and disadvantages, but allows you to more easily layout your views for each screen. In Xcode 5, you have a button at the bottom of the interface builder to see how your UI looks on smaller and larger screens.

Comment: Thanks do much for the quick reply! I think I'll try two storyboards. Cheers!